# Creating a new column in an SQL table and conditionally adding only some content from an existing column

Tags: sql

I'm working with iOS backups, and I'd like to split a single column into two columns and then move content from the original column to the new column based on the value of a third column. So any item with 0 in `is_from_me` below would be moved to a new column `text_not_from_me`.

I'm using SQLite as the RDBMS.

So this:

```
text               is_from_me  
--------           ------------      
Hi John!           0
Hi Jane.           1
How are you?       0
Not bad. You?      1
```

Would become this:

```
text            text_not_from_me      is_from_me
----------      --------------------  --------------
                 Hi John!             0
Hi Jane.                              1
                 How are you?         0
Not bad. You?                         1
```

I've tried the following but am getting an error noting that the `text_not_from_me` column doesn't exist:

```sql
SELECT
    datetime (message.date / 1000000000 + strftime ("%s", "2001-01-01"), "unixepoch", "localtime") AS message_date,
    message.text, 
    CASE
        WHEN is_from_me = 1 THEN message.text
        ELSE text_not_from_me
    END AS text_not_from_me,
    message.is_from_me,
    chat.chat_identifier

FROM
    chat
    INNER JOIN chat_message_join ON chat_message_join.chat_id    = chat."ROWID"
    INNER JOIN message           ON chat_message_join.message_id = message."ROWID"

ORDER BY
     message_date ASC;
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: When you say you want to "add a column to a table" do you mean you want to redesign the physical table (as in `CREATE TABLE`/`ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN`), or just have a query that performs the transformation on-the-fly (i.e. a `VIEW`)?

Comment: Hi @Dai. I just mean that I'd like to have a query that performs the transformation on the fly to view quickly or export into an Excel spreadsheet. I hope that clarifies.

Comment: do you have a timestamp you can use to order the texts?

Comment: Assuming that `message.date` is correctly typed as a `datetime` value, what is the purpose of trying to convert it to a UNIX timestamp?

Comment: While `INNER JOIN` [is commutative](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/160926/10044) methinks your query would be more intuitive if your derived-tables were ordered as `FROM message INNER JOIN chat_message_join  INNER JOIN chat` instead of the reverse - as it makes it easier to change to an `OUTER JOIN` if necessary.

Comment: @Dai These are for iMessages. My understanding is that the date field is epoch, starts from 2001, and measures the time at the nanosecond level.

Comment: @Dai Yes, I've updated the question to reflect this. Sorry for not mentioning in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what you want?

```sql
CREATE VIEW side_by_side_chat_messages AS

SELECT
    m."date",
    c.chat_identifier,
    CASE WHEN m.is_from_me = 1 THEN m.text END AS text_from_me,
    CASE WHEN m.is_from_me = 0 THEN m.text END AS text_not_from_me,
    m.is_from_me

FROM
    message AS m
    INNER JOIN chat_message_join AS j ON j.chat_id = m."ROWID"
    INNER JOIN chat              AS c ON j.chat_id = c."ROWID"

--ORDER BY
--    m."date"
;
```

Note that queries in `VIEW` objects do not have `ORDER BY` clauses (yes, I agree it's annoying) so it's commented-out. If you want to persist non-trivial `ORDER BY` logic in a `VIEW` then use a `ROW_NUMBER() ( PARTITION BY x ORDER BY y ) AS orderByThis` column in the `VIEW` and  expose it to consumers so they just need to add `ORDER BY orderByThis` when they query the `VIEW`.

e.g.

```sql
SELECT
    v.*
FROM
    side_by_side_chat_messages AS v
ORDER BY
    v."date"
```

Comment: For some reason, I'm getting duplicate messages when use this solution.

Comment: Please create a SQLFiddle or DBFiddle with some sample data.

Comment: I created one [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/46611/7).I'm not running into the same duplicate messages issue with this version.